# 'Extract Here' context menu item for Dolphin file manager

Tags: kde-plasma, file-manager

I installed the Dolphin file manager from Software Manager.
It's a nice file manager. I would like to get the Extract Here context menu, where you right-click on an archive and select Extract Here and it gets extracted in the same folder.. like Nemo.
I saw some services to add to the Configure Dolphin menu. I installed one and it didn't make any difference.
Any help is appreciated or kindly point me to any relevant resources. I searched a lot, but most are for KDE?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

installed Ark and that added an Extract context menu to Penguin file manager. :)
(In case it helps anyone)